# load multiple table in the same database from sql to qlikview

Tags: sql, qlikview

I am trying to load all the tables in "ABCD_BKP" which starts with TEST_

The tables in my database are as follows:

```
ABCD_BKP
   TEST_1
   TEST_2
   TEST_3
```

And I am trying to load it as per below but it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT *
FROM "ABCD_BKP".dbo.TEST_*
```

Comment: Which database did you use? `sql-server`?

Comment: Please read the tag wiki "Questions should include ... a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2) being used. If your question relates to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ANSI SQL." Please tag with your specific SQL implementation, rather than with 'SQL'.

Answer (score 3):

To load all tables you need to have list with the tables first and loop through this list and load the tables one by one.

For example if you are using MSSQL your script will be:

```
// Get all tables in "ABCD_BKP"
TableNames:
SQL
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    "ABCD_BKP".dbo.Tables
;

// Filter only table names that are starting with "TEST_"
Test_TableNames:
LOAD DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME
RESIDENT
    TableNames as TestTables
WHERE 
   LEFT(TABLE_NAME, 5) = 'TEST_'
;

DROP TABLE TableNames; // the table with all table names is no longer needed

FOR i = 1 TO FieldValue('TestTables') // loop through all "TEST_*" tables
    LET vTableName = FieldValue( 'TestTables', $(i) ); // current iteration table name

    $(vTableName): //give our QV table the same name as the SQL table
    SQL
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        "ABCD_BKP".dbo.$(vTableName) // load the sql table in QV
    ;

NEXT

DROP TABLE Test_TableNames; // drop the QV table that contains the list with the "TEST_" tables
```

The sql to get the list with the tables in database is different for each database